# How to filter RCed trait objects vector of specific subtrait in Rust?

Tags: rust, casting, ownership, rc

The task is to filter out the supertrait objects for base trait object vector:

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::any::Any;

pub trait TraitA {
    fn get_title(&self) -> &str;
    fn as_any(&self) -> Any;
}

pub trait TraitB: TraitA {
    fn get_something(&self) -> &str;
}

pub fn filter_b(input: Vec<Rc<dyn TraitA>>) -> Vec<Rc<dyn TraitB>> {
    // bs.filter(|it| /* How to do it? */).collect();
}
```

Is it even possible? Any clue or advice?

I know `as_any()` can be used to downcast but as i'm not sure how it's meant to work with `Rc` as it takes ownership (and thus requires the instance).

Answer (score 2):

I was first expecting the answer to be "absolutely not!", `Any` doesn't help if you don't know the concrete type. But it turns out you can... *with caveats*, and I'm not 100% sure its totally safe.

To go from `Rc<T>` to `Rc<U>`, you can use the escape hatches [`into_raw`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.into_raw) and [`from_raw`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.from_raw). The docs of the former read:

> Constructs an Rc from a raw pointer.
>
> The raw pointer must have been previously returned by a call to `Rc<U>::into_raw` where `U` must have the same size and alignment as `T`. This is trivially true if `U` is `T`. Note that if `U` is not `T` but has the same size and alignment, this is basically like transmuting references of different types. See [`mem::transmute`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute.html) for more information on what restrictions apply in this case.
>
> The user of `from_raw` has to make sure a specific value of `T` is only dropped once.
>
> This function is unsafe because improper use may lead to memory unsafety, even if the returned `Rc<T>` is never accessed.

With that in mind, since we only have access to `TraitA`, it'll need an `as_b()` function to get itself as a `TraitB`. The fact that the target is a super trait doesn't really help. Then we can write a `crosscast` function like so:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

trait TraitA {
    fn print_a(&self);

    // SAFETY: the resulting `dyn TraitB` must have the *exact* same address,
    // size, alignment, and drop implementation for `crosscast` to work safely.
    // Basically it must be `self` or maybe a transparently wrapped object.
    unsafe fn as_b(&self) -> Option<&(dyn TraitB + 'static)>;
}

trait TraitB {
    fn print_b(&self);
}

fn crosscast(a: Rc<dyn TraitA>) -> Option<Rc<dyn TraitB>> {
    unsafe {
        let b_ptr = a.as_b()? as *const dyn TraitB;
        let a_ptr = Rc::into_raw(a);
        
        // sanity check
        assert!(a_ptr as *const () == b_ptr as *const ());
        
        Some(Rc::from_raw(b_ptr))
    }
}
```

With this function at our disposal, your problem becomes trivial by using `.filter_map()`:

```
struct Both {
    data: String,
}

impl TraitA for Both {
    fn print_a(&self) { println!("A: {}", self.data); }
    unsafe fn as_b(&self) -> Option<&(dyn TraitB + 'static)> { Some(self) }
}

impl TraitB for Both {
    fn print_b(&self) { println!("B: {}", self.data); }
}

struct OnlyA {
    data: String,
}

impl TraitA for OnlyA {
    fn print_a(&self) { println!("A: {}", self.data); }
    unsafe fn as_b(&self) -> Option<&(dyn TraitB + 'static)> { None }
}

fn main() {
    let vec_a = vec![
        Rc::new(Both{ data: "both".to_owned() }) as Rc<dyn TraitA>,
        Rc::new(OnlyA{ data: "only a".to_owned() })
    ];

    for a in &vec_a {
        a.print_a();
    }
    
    println!();
    
    let vec_b = vec_a
        .into_iter()
        .filter_map(crosscast)
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    for b in &vec_b {
        b.print_b();
    }
}
```

See it all together on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fd00d6692da490b9ec12310e5fc28347).

I would still recommend not doing this if at all possible. It would be perfectly safe for example to go from `&Rc<dyn TraitA>` to `Option<&dyn TraitB>` using the above method without all the restrictions. Something like this wouldn't have the restrictions and unsafety:

```
for b in vec_a.iter().filter_map(|a| a.as_b()) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: that might work, thanks. However Rust is declared to have no-price abstraction and i'd love to have a safe solution to this if possible (even for the price of adding some modifications to the traits or impls).

Comment: BTW, i'm not sure if you noticed, `TraitB: TraitA` is important. Doe it make the task a bit easier?

Comment: *"Rust is declared to have no-price abstraction"* - I'm not sure what you're trying to say here, the *language* isn't imposing any "costs" here. It's `Rc` that imposes the requirements and there's next to no runtime cost for this. If *every* `A` was a `B` this might be more straight-forward, but if its conditional there must be something dictating that condition and therefore has room to break `Rc`s invariants. `TraitB: TraitA` doesn't establish a relationship to go from `A` to `B`. This might be harder to break and therefore safer with the upcoming specialization, but I haven't explored that.